# Sitecore: Seemingly Random errors appear

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

we are experiencing some very odd errors in our installation. 
Some times out of nowhere Sitecore throws an error:

```
Assert: Value Cannot be null. Parameter: Item.
```

The closest i have come to identifying the problem is narrowing it down to either an index or the web database.

Anyway, if I log into sitecore the Item is just missing, i can fix it in 3 ways:

- Rebuild the index.
- Recycle app pool
- `iisreset`

Does any of you have an idea why this might be happening? We are running Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 120706). Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I used to have a similar problem while having couple browser tabs open and using different Sitecore databases in them, e.g. open page editor from Sitecore desktop as a new tab, then switch the desktop to the Core database, and then trying to do something in the page editor once again (without switching desktop back to Master database).

Comment: Is this happening in the web or master database, and is it experienced by content authors or end users? Also, do you have any information on what item is missing?

Comment: The index always has some staleness, so when pulling a Sitecore item based on an index entry make sure that the item exists.  I have seen this happen especially with deleting an item and doing some combination of publishing the item's parent or vice versa.

Comment: Are you using the advanced database crawler for your Lucene queries?

Comment: @MarkUrsino yeah I am actually, but i'm not quering it at the time of the error...

Comment: Based on that info, I've added a possible answer if you're seeing issues base don the index.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem, website is not stable. We are also using Sitecore scaling environments and only problem fixed by IISreset/App pool recycle. Please let us know, if you have any update.

Comment: Scan your code for "new Database", if you are in an environment where you can't access the Sitecore Context you should not use this approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing a system stability issue, so I recommend opening a ticket with Sitecore support (http://support.sitecore.net). This sort of issue is difficult to troubleshoot over Stack Overflow, since we do  not have access to your logs and configuration.

When opening the ticket, I recommend using the [Support Package Generator](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Resources/Tools/Support%20Package%20Generator.aspx) which bundles up all the information (Web.config, App_Config files, IIS settings, Sitecore log files) that Sitecore Support needs to troubleshoot the issue.  It's a pretty nifty tool.

That said, from what you describe, it sounds like the issue is related to caching.  The fact that restarting IIS resolves the issue indicates that the item is in the Web database, but the runtime doesn't see it.  You can prove out whether this is the issue by clearing cache using the /sitecore/admin/cache.aspx screen.  If your cache is not getting updated properly, you should review your configuration against the guidelines in the SDN [Scaling Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Scaling%20Guide.aspx).

Comment: I have now opened a support ticket with sitecore, and is waiting to see what happens

Comment: Cool! Let us know what the issue turns out to be.

Comment: I am also facing similar problem, website is not stable. We are also using Sitecore scaling environments and only problem fixed by IISreset/App pool recycle. Please let us know, if you have any update.

Comment: Better Late than never: Embarrasingly enough I had a "new Database" in my code which was running in a webservice. causing Sitecore to restart and reindex the Items. Then sometimes this would happen multiple times in a row, causing the problem I described

Answer (score 2):

Based on knowing you're using the Advanced Database Crawler, your issue may be how you're converting a `SkinnyItem` to an `Item`. I've had this issue before. If you look at the [SkinnyItem.cs class](http://svn.sitecore.net/AdvancedDatabaseCrawler/Branches/v2/Sitecore.SharedSource.Searcher/SkinnyItem.cs), there's a `GetItem()` method to convert it into an `Item`. You can see it uses the database to get the item by its ID, language, and version number. Its possible that when you publish from master to web, you are publishing a new version # of an existing item and thus the new version exists in the web DB, but the index is not updated and references the old version. So, this `GetItem()` call would use the previous version # and the item would be null. One way to fix this is instead of calling that `GetItem()` method, just use your own code to get the latest version of that item from Sitecore, e.g.

```
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(someSkinnyItem.ItemID);
```

Instead of

```
Item item = someSkinnyItem.GetItem();
```

Here's an example flow:

- Foo item created in master DB as version 1.
- Publish Foo to web
- Index will pick up version 1 in web DB and put in index.
- Any querying code against index will convert the `SkinnyItem` to an `Item` via that `GetItem()` method and will pass 1 as the version #.
- Page will load, no error in log
- Back in master, create version 2 of Foo and publish.
- Index may not get updated right away or even if configured wrong.
- Code that looks against index will call `GetItem()` and still call with version 1 since that's in the index
- But when you published, web no longer has version 1, it now has version 2, and thus that specific version of that item Foo is null
- Error shows in log

On a similar note, [here's a blog post by Alex Shyba](http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2012/07/sync-up-sitecore-search-index-update.html) (creator of the ADC) on how to sync HTML cache clearing with the index updates. That may help.

Comment: +1 Really useful stuff, Mark, thanks! One thing I'm wondering though--why does doing either an IIS or App Pool recycle resolve the issue?  Wouldn't the index still be stale?

Comment: Great question, and it *may* not be the index, that was just a suspicion of mine. Do you have any `Item` or `SkinnyItem` references in your code in static members of classes? If so, a static member remains in memory across all pages and will not dispose from page to page, so so an IIS Reset / recycle will flush that from memory

Comment: I am using the sitecore way to get items.
foreach (SkinnyItem si in itms)
            {
                    Item i = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(si.ItemID, LanguageManager.GetLanguage("da"));
                    if (i != null)
                    {
                       resItems.Add(new CarSortingHelper(i));
                    }                
            }