# Need help for troubleshooting/diagnostic Sitecore Website

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Few days we stuck in different problem after code drop. Everything was fine earlier but after code drop Memory and CPU uses are approx 100% and even website was not stable. It was throwing errors 'Value cannot be null'. But Sitecore admin interface was always accessible and we can preview website from Master Database.

We did publish (Republish  Site/Nodes, Smart publish, incremental publish also) but cannot figure out problem. Could you please help, how could we troubleshoot in such situation?

Comment: Any useful messages in your Sitecore logs? Is this the same across all servers (Dev/QA/Pre-Prod)? Can you replicate the problem in another environment? What troubleshooting steps have you tried? http://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/sitecore-troubleshooting-path/

Comment: Thanks for attention. Sitecore logs reports error same as 'Value cannot be null', we replicated same thing on DEV box, it also started crying as same. One more important thing - we are using Sitecore scaling environments.

Comment: What is the Parameter it is throwing the error on? So you get the error on master or web? Content Editor or front end? I'd recommend contacing Sitecore Support as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13459522/661447

Comment: I am getting error in Web database while browsing website on front end for content Editor it previewing website perfectly. I am getting exact similar error which is reported in link which you suggested.

Comment: That suggests to me you are missing some items or templates in the web database. If you can replicate by going to specific pages then make sure all related content is published. Check your web database to make sure it is there and not in workflow or there are publish restrictions. Double check your config files for web are correct.

Comment: So finally did you get anywhere after the suggestions from @jammykam and an answer from Jay S?

Comment: No, tough luck. I am still trying to dig into it.

Comment: I solved out this problem and solution provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your providing help.

We solved this issue while analyzing root cause.

Sitecore was running agents after certain time interval and it was failing to complete it because on dependency on another thing. So at last all thing mess with creating a dead end loop. Which was eating all CPU memories. So it was not communicating well with database servers to get data.

After resetting IIS, all jobs are ended for a while and it works after same dead loop.

Answer (score 0):

If preview is working and the main website is not, you likely have content items (either templates, sublayouts, or fields) that are not in a publishable state.

If you still have the package you used to install your update, it should have the content items that were added, which would help you track down which items to check for.

Additionally, you can write code to crawl your Templates tree and find any items that are not in the final state of workflow.

Comment: You should check out the [Published Item Comparer](http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2011/04/29/published-item-comparer/) module